# Laravel get values that contains string in where clause

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get in where clause the cities that contains certain string.

For example, if I search for 'Alexandria' I want the results to have also 'Alexandria' and 'Alexandria, Romania' results.

I tried the following code but this is not working:

```
if(!is_null($city)){
  $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
  ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
  ->where('city', 'like', '%'.$city.'%');
}
```

I also tried the following way but it throws ' Column not found: 1054'.

```
if(!is_null($city)){
  $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
  ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
  ->where(strpos('city', $city) === true);
}
```

Can you please help me with some ideas on how can I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: your first try is correct. what is the error?

Comment: Hi @Babak, with the first try if I search for 'Alexandria' I get both 'Alexandria' and 'Alexandria, Romania'. But if i search for 'Alexandria, Romania' I only get 'Alexandria, Romania' without 'Alexandria'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first explode `$city` by space and then use `orWhere` with `like`

```
if(!is_null($city)){
  $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
  ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
  ->Where(function ($q) use($city) {
          $words = explode(' ',$city);
          foreach ($words as $word){
          $q->orwhere('city', 'like',  '%' . $word .'%');
      }      
   });
}
```

i think there are better solutions but this is what i found for now.

Comment: Hi @babek, this solution works good, any idea on how to get also 'Alexandria' values when I search for 'Alexandria, Romania'?

Comment: I found, I had to change  $words = explode(' ',$city); to   $words = explode(', ',$city);

Answer (score 1):

You have to split it up with an explode on the ','. You might also like to try ', ' (with a space at end) depending on how consistent your data is and if you need the country part of the string to be searchable.

Note that I changed your original input variable to $searchTerm, and it gets split into $city.

```
function ($query) use ($searchTerm, $max_price, $min_price) {
    if (! empty($searchTerm)) {
        // Break search string apart into separate search terms. Split on comma.
        foreach (explode(',', $searchTerm) as $city) {
            // For every search term check if it can be found in any of the searchable fields.
            $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
            ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
            ->where('city', 'like', '%'.$city.'%');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! 